# Querydsl join on same table multiple times

Tags: java, querydsl

Let's say I have two tables `Task` and `Company`. `Company` has columns `id` and `name`. `Task` has two columns `customerId` and `providerId` which link back to the `id` column for `Company`.

Using Querydsl how do I join on the `Company` table twice so I can get the `name` for each company specified by the `customerId` and `providerId`?

Code that maybe explains better what I'm trying:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(templates);
JPASQLQuery query = new JPASQLQuery(this.entityManager, configuration);

QTask task = QTask.task;
QCompany customer = QCompany.company;
QCompany provider = QCompany.company;

JPASQLQuery sql = query.from(task).join(customer).on(customer.id.eq(task.customerId))
    .join(provider).on(provider.id.eq(task.providerId));

return sql.list(task.id, customer.name.as("customerName"), provider.name.as("providerName"));
```

Which generates SQL:

```
select task.id, company.name as customerName, company.name as providerName from task join company on company.id = task.customerId
```

And I'd really like it to be:

```
select task.id, customer.name as customerName, provider.name as providerName from task join company as customer on customer.id = task.customerId join company as provider on provider.id = task.providerId
```

I couldn't figure out how to alias the table I was joining so I could distinguish between customer and provider names. I tried doing `new QCompany("company as provider")` but that didn't work. Anyone know how one can do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you need to variables just do the following

```
QCompany customer = new QCompany("customer");
QCompany provider = new QCompany("provider");
```

Reassignment of the default variable `QCompany.company` doesn't help

Comment: Thanks Timo, but that creates a query with a table "customer" and a table "provider". Those tables don't exist. It's just one table called company. If it would do "company as customer" and "company as provider" that would work great.

Comment: If QCompany is an APT based generated class you query won't work, you will need to use JPAQuery for this case. JPASQLQuery is for SQL queries with Q-types generated using this approach http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.1/reference/html/ch02s03.html#d0e668

Comment: Bummer, that sucks. Is this an intentional thing or something I can open a ticket for?

Comment: That's intentional, but you can open a ticket for it. At least it should be better documented. How did you end up picking JPASQLQuery?

Comment: I'm using spring-data-jpa and so I have everything annotated, but I need to do some reporting which needs to pick from a bunch of things that don't necessarily connect in the way the JPAQuery wants them to be. So JPASQLQuery seemed a nice in between where I could use all my annotations to generate the classes but still join things with foreign keys in sql instead of creating a full entity graph in my code. And I could just use the EntityManager I already had setup instead of pulling the connection out of it to use SQLQuery. It all worked too except this lack of aliasing.